# user defined pointer wrapper and nullptr comparison does not call the operator I have provided

Tags: c++, c++17, operator-overloading, nullptr

I want to compare if my `my_ptr` object is `nullptr` or not. I expected `x == nullptr` to call the following operator I have provided.

```
operator==(std::nullptr_t, const my_ptr<V>& r)
```

but it is not getting called. I don't see " == nullptr called" displayed on my output screen. And also if I uncomment the following line

```
my_ptr<int> x2{p2}
```

the result flips. I checked this behaviour in g++ and some online compilers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class my_ptr
{
    T* t = nullptr;

  public:
    my_ptr() 
    {
        std::cout<<"\n No arguments constructor called\n";
    }

    my_ptr(std::nullptr_t) 
    {
        std::cout<<"\n nullptr constructor called\n";
    }

    my_ptr(T* t_)
        : t(t_)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n pointer constructor called\n";
    }
  
    operator const void*() const 
    {
        std::cout<<"\n void param called ";
        return t; 
    }

};

template <typename U, typename V>
bool operator==(const my_ptr<U>& l, const my_ptr<V>& r)
{
    std::cout<<"\n == called\n";
    return l.get() == r.get();
}

template <typename U, typename V>
bool operator==(std::nullptr_t, const my_ptr<V>& r)
{
    std::cout<<"\n == nullptr called\n";
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    int *p;
    my_ptr<int> x{p};
   
    int *p2;
    my_ptr<int> x2{p2}; //uncommenting this line changes the result value
 
    std::cout<<"\n "<<int(x == nullptr)<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output seen

1. with my_ptr x2{p2}; **commented**

> pointer constructor called
>
> void param called 0

2. with my_ptr x2{p2}; **un-commented**

> pointer constructor called
>
> pointer constructor called
>
> void param called 1

Comment: The behaviour of the program is undefined, because you read the value of uninitialised pointers `p` and `p2`.

Comment: Change `int *p;` to `int *p{};`.  Change `int *p2;` to `int *p2{};`.  That will eliminate the undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your operator.

> ```
> template <typename U, typename V>
> bool operator==(std::nullptr_t, const my_ptr<V>& r)
> {
>     std::cout<<"\n == nullptr called\n";
>     return false;
> }
> ```

It has a template argument `U` that cannot be deduced from the function parameters, hence you cannot use it with operator call syntax `x == y`.

Second, you defined `operator==(std::nullptr_t,const my_ptr<V>&)` but you call `operator==(const my_ptr<V>&,std::nullptr_t)`. Before C++20 you need to explicitly implement the other order, also when the operator is symmetric.

You get expected output with this `operator==`:

```
template <typename V>
bool operator==(const my_ptr<V>&, std::nullptr_t)
{
    std::cout<<"\n == nullptr called\n";
    return false;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7GGP6oETY)

As pointed out by DaveS, since C++20, implementing `operator(std::nullptr,cosnt my_ptr<V>&)` is sufficient to call `x == nullptr`.

Last but not least, your code has undefined behavior due to using `p` and `p1` when they are uninitialized.

Comment: Note, in C++20, `operator ==` has some rules to make it symmetric.  See https://godbolt.org/z/9ov815Yhv (C++20) vs. https://godbolt.org/z/8ax35K66z (C++17).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Without the correct operator that you have provided, which operator was called in my case and why the result changes when I comment and un-comment the line.?

Comment: @user3219492 `why the result changes when I comment and un-comment the line.?` [Because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71943208/user-defined-pointer-wrapper-and-nullptr-comparison-does-not-call-the-operator-i#comment127126850_71943208) the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: @user3219492 -- at a glance, the comparison probably uses the object's conversion to `void*`.

Comment: @user3219492 i dont see the UB, but I also cannot reproduce the `1` in the output. Without the right `operator==` the conversion to pointer via `operator const void*() const` was taken. I strongly recommend to make this conversion explicit, because implicit conversion can cause confusing bugs, especially as you are overloading operators where pointers are involved

Comment: @PeteBecker I see, you are saying the == operation is calling void* on my my_ptr object. Makes sense

Comment: @user3219492 oh well the UB is due to the pointers in `main` not being initialized. You should always initialize variables as soon as you declared them